# Scrapy and DynamoDB: Passing a timestamp

Tags: python, scrapy, amazon-dynamodb

At this moment I collect a timestamp directly from the website I parse but I noticed they don't differentiate am/pm. Is there a way to make DynamoDB or the script to put a timestamp with proper time (am/pm)? The only thing I could find was creation_time (boto3) but that's for the table. Any suggestions? Thank you.

My pipeline:

```
class DynamoDBStorePipeline(object):

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb',region_name="us-west-2")

    table = dynamodb.Table('x')

    table.put_item(
    Item={
    'url': str(item['url']),
    'title': item['title'].encode('utf-8'),
    'stamp': item['stamp'].encode('utf-8'),
    }
    )
    return item
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a nice plugin on pip directory:

```
pip install tstamp
```

and using there documentation was able to pass a timestamp